# Adding a Data Attribute to a dynamically created button when a user selects from a select box

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a jquery mobiile app which has hundreds of tables included within it. I've added a dynamic row to the end of each of these tables which includes a button with a "data-name" attribute derived directly from the table header of that table.

These tables are used to catalogue different types of product, some of which have different sizes per model, and some don't. What I'd like to be able to do is for those that have multiple sizes per model, add a select box to the table which will then update the data-name attribute to include this user selected size.

So far, I've managed to get the select box to update the text at the bottom rather than adding it to the corresonding button at the end...

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Model</th>
            <th>1</th>
            <th>2</th>
            <th>3</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Weight</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Size</td>
            <td class="sizeSelect">
            <select>
                <option data-size="option1">Option 1</option>
                <option data-size="option2">Option 2</option>
                <option data-size="option3">Option 3</option>
                <option data-size="option4">Option 4</option>
             </select>
            </td>
            <td>
            <select>
                <option data-size="option1">Option 1</option>
                <option data-size="option2">Option 2</option>
                <option data-size="option3">Option 3</option>
                <option data-size="option4">Option 4</option>
             </select>
            </td>
            <td>
            <select>
                <option data-size="option1">Option 1</option>
                <option data-size="option2">Option 2</option>
                <option data-size="option3">Option 3</option>
                <option data-size="option4">Option 4</option>
             </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>something</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>else</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Model</th>
            <th>HTL-L4</th>
            <th>HTL-L8</th>
            <th>HTL-L</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Weight</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Size</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>something</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>else</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

add to there's the script...

```
// appends a row to the bottom of the tables for Add to Cart Button to be inserted into 
            $('table > tbody').append('<tr class="cartRow"></tr>');
            $('table > tbody > tr:last-child').append('<td>Enquire Now</td>');

            $('table').each(function() {
                var $this = $(this);
                $('tbody > tr > th:not(:first)', this).each(function(){


                    // appends a cell to the row  
                    $('tbody > tr:last-child', $this)
                      .append('<td class="cartButton"><a class="add-to-cart button" data-name="'+$(this).text()+'" href="#basket" style="padding-top:0 !important;margin-bottom:0 !important; height: 3rem !important; line-height: 3rem !important;">Add</a></td>');
                });

        $('select', $this).change(function(){

       $variable = $(this).find(':selected').data('size');

        $('.cartButton a', $this).text($variable);


        });
```

Comment: Why not use a second data-attribute for size: https://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/n81hrwoj/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to add the selected size to the `data-name` attribute of the button, so this should do that:

Change this:

```
$('.cartButton a', $this).text($variable);
```

To this:

```
$buttondata = $('.cartButton a', $this).data("name") + ', size ' + $variable;
$('.cartButton a', $this).data("name",$buttondata);
```

With this code, you should end up with this in `data-name`: [previous data], size [size data]

Comment: Hi Sjt AJ, Thanks for the reply. When I do this it seems like all I get is the model name in the data-name (I.e data-name=1) It doesn't seem to add the appropriate select value to the end of the attribute.

Comment: So data-name holds a single number before the size is added?  Try echoing $buttondata after you assign it and before you put it into the data-name attribute to make sure it contains what you think it should.